# How to find a random unit vector orthogonal to a random unit vector in 3D?

Tags: vectors, parametric, random

I have a unit circle with the center at the origin $O=(0, 0, 0)$ and a random unit vector $\bar U = (a, b, c)$, in the Cartesian coordinate system. How can I find a random unit vector orthogonal to $\bar U$?

My try was to find an intersection of my sphere and plane, which passes through the origin and has $\bar U$ as a normal vector, and then to define a point on this unit circle randomly.

So I have the system of equations:
\begin{cases}
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1, \\
ax + by + cz = 0,
\end{cases}
and I wanted to set the solutions of this system parametrically but I got stuck. I know how to set the solutions in particular cases (e.g. when $a=c\neq0$) but I have no idea for the general one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are only interested in a numerical solution rather than a parametric one you can do the following:

If we call $\vec{n}=(a,b,c)$ than the corresponding unit vector is $\hat{n} = \frac{\vec{n}}{| \vec{n}|}$. Now generate a uniformly distributed random point $\vec{r}$ inside a sphere of radius 1.

Form the vector $\vec{u} = \vec{r} - \left( \vec{r}.\hat{n} \right) \hat{n}$. It is easy to see that this vector is perpendicular to $\vec{n}$. So if you normalise it you get a random unitvector $\hat{u}$ that is perpendicular to the normal of your circle.

There is of course a slight numerical problem if the random vector $\vec{r}$ is almost parallel to the normal. You could repeat generating the random vector $\vec{r}$ until the angle it makes with the normal is sufficiently large.

For a parametric solution, use a simple perpendicular vector $\vec{u} = (b, -a,0)$ and calculate the cross product $\vec{v} = \vec{n} \times \vec{u}$, normalise both and take a linear combination $\hat{w} = \cos \theta \hat{u} + \sin \theta \hat{v}$ with a uniformly distributed random $\theta \in [0,2 \pi]$.

Comment: The method for computing the first orthogonal vector $\vec{u}$ fails for the case of $\vec{n} = (0, 0, c)$.  A safer choice is $\vec{u} = (b - c, -a + c, a - b)$.

Comment: @CuriousKea You, are right of course. Most methods have some special directions where they fail. Depending on the problem at hand, one typically relies on the fact that it is unlikely for this direction to occur or prevent the issue   by using a set of conditionals, i.e. choose a suitable $\vec{u}$ among $(b,-a,0)$, $(c,0,-a)$, or $(0,c,-b)$. Note that in your case, the problem occurs for vectors close to the $(1,1,1)$ direction.

Comment: Argh! Good point! Thanks for noticing that because I'm using that method right now. I see my suggestion is problematic for any case close to $a = b = c$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume your reference vector be $\mathbb{x}=(1,0,0)$, then the normal unit vector would be
$\mathbf{n} =(0,\cos{t},\sin{t}) \quad |\; -\pi<t \le \pi$, where $t$ is a parameter.
So, for $t$ uniformly distributed in its range,
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
 \mathbf n \; \text{is a "unit random vector", normal to }\; \mathbf x }$$ (if I understood what you mean by that).

Now, instead, your reference vector is $\mathbf {v}=(a,b,c)$, with $|\mathbf {v}|=1$, which can be written in terms of polar angles as
$\mathbf {v}=(cos{\theta}cos{\phi},cos{\theta}sin{\phi},sin{\theta})$, with:
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
   - \pi  < \varphi  = \arctan _4 (a,b) \le \pi  \hfill \cr 
   - \pi /2 \le \vartheta  = \arctan \left( {{c \over {\sqrt {a^{\,2}  + b^{\,2} } }}} \right) \le \pi /2 \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

The Rotation Matrices giving a rotation with angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ (with sign taken according to the *right hand rule*)
respectively around the $y$ and the $z$ axis are:
$$
R_{\,z} (\varphi ) = \left( {\matrix{
   {\cos \varphi } & { - \sin \varphi } & 0  \cr 
   {\sin \varphi } & {\cos \varphi } & 0  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 1  \cr 
 } } \right)\quad R_{\,y} (\vartheta ) = \left( {\matrix{
   {\cos \vartheta } & 0 & {\sin \vartheta }  \cr 
   0 & 1 & 0  \cr 
   { - \sin \vartheta } & 0 & {\cos \vartheta }  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$

Therefore
$$
{\bf v} = R_{\,z} (\varphi )\;R_{\,y} ( - \vartheta )\;{\bf x}
$$

and the vector $\mathbf{n}'$ you are looking for is equivalently given by:
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
{\bf n}'(t) = R_{\,z} (\varphi )\;R_{\,y} ( - \vartheta )\;{\bf n}(t)
}$$

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old-ish question, but here is a solution that is rather simple and always works.

Let's denote a generic unit vector $ \boldsymbol{u} = (a, b, c)$, such that $|i|\neq 1$, for $i = a, b, c$. It is easy to show that, no matter the choice of $ \boldsymbol{u} $, the following three vectors are always orthogonal to $\boldsymbol{u}$:

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{v}_a = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ c \\ -b \end{pmatrix}
\quad
\boldsymbol{v}_b = \begin{pmatrix} -c \\ 0 \\ a \end{pmatrix}
\quad
\boldsymbol{v}_c = \begin{pmatrix} b \\ -a \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Furthermore, using the cross product, one can find a third set of vectors $\boldsymbol{w}_i$ that are orthogonal to $\boldsymbol{u}$ and $\boldsymbol{v}_i$:

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{w}_a = \begin{pmatrix} a^2 - 1 \\ ab \\ ac \end{pmatrix}
\quad
\boldsymbol{w}_b = \begin{pmatrix} ab \\ b^2-1 \\ bc \end{pmatrix}
\quad
\boldsymbol{w}_c = \begin{pmatrix} ac \\ bc \\ c^2-1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Each triplet $(\boldsymbol{u}, \boldsymbol{v}_i, \boldsymbol{w}_i)$ is a basis of orthogonal vectors by construction. Finally, it can be shown that the expression

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{p}_i = \boldsymbol{v}_i \frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1-i^2}} + \boldsymbol{w}_i \frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{1-i^2}}
\end{equation}

generates all unit vectors that are orthogonal to $\boldsymbol{u}$ when changing $\theta$ between $0$ and $2\pi$ - this is the parameteric solution that OP was looking for.

Note that the procedure above provides 3 distinct parameterizations. However, each of them has a singularity when $i^2 = 1$, in which case $\boldsymbol{v}_i$ and $\boldsymbol{w}_i$ both become null - this is why I initially added the hypothesis that $|a|\neq 1$,  $|b|\neq 1$ and  $|c|\neq 1$. However, only one of the three triplets can be singular at a time. The "bullet-proof strategy" is to select as $i$ the closest to zero between $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Here is a Python-NumPy code that calculates the vectors:

````
def get_vw(u):
    # Make a permutation of the indices so that the least value is always "a"
    i = np.argmin(np.abs(u))
    a, b, c = np.roll(u.copy(), -i)
    
    # Calculate v and w using the formulae for v_a and w_a 
    d = np.sqrt(1 - a**2)
    v = np.array([0, c/d, -b/d])
    w = np.array([-d, a*b/d, a*c/d])

    # Perform the inverse permutation when returning the result
    return np.roll(v, i), np.roll(w, i)
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Orthogonal is equivalent to dot product being zero. Doesn't $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}(-b,a,0)$ work?

Comment: Unless $a=b=0.$

Comment: @mfl: Of course you have to do cases, but wlog we will assume that at least two are non-zero, otherwise this is way too easy since you can just use one of the standard unit basis vector $\textbf{e}_j$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not exactly what I want. My question was not sufficiently accurate. I've specified the question. I need a random unit vector.

Comment: @colombien: The vector I present is a "random one". The quantities $a,b$ aren't fixed real numbers. Once you go through the cases (given below), you realize that for the set of "random" vectors orthogonal to $\bar{U}$, you can write them explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

At least two of $(b,-a,0)$, $(c,0,-a)$ and $(0,c,-b)$ will be nonzero,
so you can normalise one of them.

There is no continuous map $f$ from unit vectors to unit vectors
with $v\cdot f(v)=0$. This is the Hairy Ball Theorem. This means
there probably won't be a "nice" closed formula for a perpendicular unit vector.